# Webpack Hot-Reload Middleware in ASP.NET 4.6

Tags: webpack, .net-4.6

I'm trying to integrate webpack in 4.6 ASP.NET project, the following line works for ASP.NET Core in startup:

```
app.UseWebpackDevMiddleware(new WebpackDevMiddlewareOptions
      {
        HotModuleReplacement = true,
        ConfigFile = "config/webpack.config.js"
      });
      ConfigureAuth(app);
```

error says IAppBuilder does not contain definition for 'UserWebpackDevMiddleware', and also 'WebpackDevMiddlewareOptions' can't be referenced, any idea what/which are the counterparts of these configurations in 4.6?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatly, the HotModuleReplacement module is available only for ASP.NET Core. You won't be able to use this syntaxe for ASP.Net MVC 4.6.
But, you can find some libraries that do the same work. Search on google using these words : "Use Webpack and Hot Module Replacement with System.Web (ASP.NET) projects"